# Outbound Web.Config URL rewrite

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, redirect, url-rewriting

This way I can redirect inbound:

```
<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="StaticRewrites">
      <add key="/documentation.html" value="/support" />
```

This way I can redirect outbound:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="breaking changes 12 redirection" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url="support/breaking_changes_12" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://company.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015680XXX-Breaking-Changes-12" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="breaking changes redirection" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url="support/breaking_changes" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://company.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/sections/360002839XXX-Older-versions" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>
```

The problem is that it wins always `breaking_changes` on `breaking_changes_12`. How can avoid this? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The rewrite looks correct and works when I tested it locally with a redirect. `test.com/support/breaking_changes_12` and `test.com/support/breaking_changes` redirect to their correct urls. Note that once a redirect is used and then changed, you'll see the effects only on clearing browser cache.

Comment: You are right, I've noticed a difference between using `www.domain.com/support/breaking_changes` and `domain.com/support/breaking_changes`. Does it make sense?

Comment: Could be that one is cached wrong. Try another browser or clear the cache. Maybe even flush your local dns.